# CMD Batch file to run R code. How can I choose different version of R?

Tags: windows, r

I have a piece of R code which I want to run periodically. So I use CMD batch file to run it. The command is something like:

R CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "/mylocalDir/myRcode.r"

I have different version of R installed in my windows. With some version installed some particular package that only works for that version. Thus I need to specify which version of R I need to run in the CMD command. I'm just wondering how I can specify that. Or can I set a default R version?

Thx!

Comment: It's the same with any program in Windows, set the full path to invoke the program or put the path to the program before another with the same name in the relevant environment variable. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved running scheduled batch job using the Windows Task Scheduler.

Your latest installed R version is the default. If you want to run the specific version, call it explicitly in your call, e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "windows not linux path :P.R"
```